# How to use ng-href in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I got some error when I use ng-href in hyper link ..

> Can't bind to 'ng-href' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

```html
<ion-content class="bg" >
<div *ngFor="let deltaa of delta">
    <ion-list> 
      <div [innerHTML] = "'<p>' + 'deltaa.GoogleMap' + '</p>'"></div> 
      <a ng-href="{{deltaa.MobileNumber}}" style="color:#f3d303">{{deltaa.MobileNumber}}</a>
    </ion-list>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I think,You can use this ex: <a data-ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="{{deltaa.MobileNumber}}" > . I'm also doing the same stuff. It's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-href is an AngularJs tag. In Angular (v2+) should be:

```
<a [href]="deltaa.MobileNumber" style="color:#f3d303">{{deltaa.MobileNumber}}</a>
```

Comment: and also can you tell me how can i use this     <div [innerHTML] = "'<p>' + 'deltaa.GoogleMap' + '</p>'"></div>   i want to show the map from database  how can i bind this